# Como puedo actualizar una variable php en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, html, css

> lo que necesito es actualizar en tiempo real el valor del span.
>   ya lo intente usando setinterval y getelementbyid pero crea conflicto con el otro script y no lee el valor de un id, lo unico que nesesito es que se actualice el valor del span cada minuto o menos espero y me puedan ayudar

```
percent = $('.bar div span').html();
total = $('.bar').attr('data-total');
percentStart = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  $('.show').css('height',percentStart/total*100+'%');
  $('.bar').css('height',percentStart/total*100+'%');
  $('.bar div span').html(Math.floor(percentStart/total*100)+'%');
  if(percentStart<percent) {
    percentStart=percentStart+5;
  }},1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="show"></div>
  <div class="bar" data-total="1000">  
  <div><span>750</span></div></div>
  <div class="suitcase">
```

Comment: ¿Declaraste `percent`, `total` y `percentStart`como var o let? Considera tambien el tiempo del setInterval, si deseas que sea cada segundo utiliza 1000.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien qué debiera contener `.show`. Pero, en fin, si le vas a dar un alto porcentual a un div, tiene que ser el porcentaje de algo que el dom entienda. Para este ejemplo le puse un contenedor con alto fijo. De esa manera `.bar` crece proporcionalmente a la altura del padre.

```js
let percent = $('.bar div span').html(),
  total = $('.bar').attr('data-total'),
  percentStart = 0,
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    let contentHeight=percentStart / total * 100;
    $('.show').css('height', contentHeight+'%');
    $('.bar').css('height',contentHeight+'%');
    $('.bar div span').html(Math.floor(contentHeight) + '%');
    if (percentStart < percent) {
      percentStart = percentStart + 25;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 50);
```

```css
.contenedor {
  height: 150px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contenedor">
<div class="show"></div>

  <div class="bar" data-total="1000" style="height:0">
    <div><span>750</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ojo, al terminar el ciclo, es mejor que termines el interval, sino éste seguirá para siempre sin sentido.